# Cant create component userControl in windows form:

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

In my project "teacher_gui_windows_form" I am trying to drag a userControl that I made from the toolbox to my form "teacher_gui" but it gives me the error:
"Failed to create component 'StudentControl'. The error message follows: System.MissingMethodException Constructor on type 'teacher_gui_windows_form.StudentControl' not found."

But I do have a StudentControl constructor.
The StudentControl class uses another form, and here is its class code:

```
public partial class StudentControl : UserControl
{
    const int Num = 10;
    Image image;
    string message;
    public StudentForm studentForm = null;

    public StudentControl(Image image, string Ip, int index)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.image = image;
        pictureBoxImage.Image = image;
        labelIp.Text = Ip;
        Location = new Point(index % Num * (Width + 5), index / Num * (Height + 5));
    }

    public void ChangeImage(Image image)
    {
        pictureBoxImage.Image = image;
    }

    private void StudentControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        studentForm = new StudentForm(pictureBoxImage.Image);
        studentForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void pictureBoxImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        studentForm = new StudentForm(pictureBoxImage.Image);
        studentForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void labelIp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        studentForm = new StudentForm(pictureBoxImage.Image);
        studentForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void seizeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void sendMessageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't expect your mouse to cough up valid arguments for that constructor.  You must provide one that takes no arguments.  Or write code instead of using the mouse.

Answer (score 6):

To create an instance of your UserControl, the Windows Forms Designer requires a parameterless constructor.  It doesn't know anything about the parameters (`Image image, string Ip, int index`) your current constructor requires, and it will not automatically generate bogus values to feed in.